# How to determine effective angular range in an area of a sphere

Tags: spherical-coordinates, angle, spheres

I have populated a sphere using the Lambert's azimuthal projection method to obtain a uniform grid/area - see link for reference to the paper (https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2010/12/aa15278-10/aa15278-10.html).

The generated sphere is shown in the image attached [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUAUi.png), and I would like to calculate the angular range that each area occupies. I have identified 4 points on the sphere and their respective azimuthal and elevation angles. So my question is - how do I calculate the effective angular range that each area on the sphere contains?

Hope that is clear. Thank you.

*Edit: Added another image of the sphere from a different angle [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm4Ou.png).

Comment: When you say "each area", do you imagine that the entire surface of the sphere is neatly tiled by little rectangular regions with corners at four grid points like the ones you have marked in the figure? The simple fact that there are fewer grid points in the upper ring than in the lower ring shows that such a tiling is not possible.

Comment: As far as I understand how these things work (correct me if you know better), the "pixels" in a grid like this are the _centers_ of their cells, not the corners. (https://healpix.jpl.nasa.gov/) I do not yet see exactly how to identify the boundaries of the cells in your illustration. What exactly do you mean by "effective angular range"?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply. I apologize if there are mistakes in my explanation as I am still quite new to this.

So I am not concerned regarding how the surface of the sphere is tiled. I presume by following the equations in the paper, I should be able to generate nodes which distributes the surface equally. As for the nodes/pixels on the grid, you are right, they represent the centers of the cells. Referring to the link you have shown, how do I determine the the range of angles that the individual cell contains?

Comment: To perhaps add some context - I have a micrograph of polycrystalline grains that contain different orientations and the grains are also oriented with two angles. What I wanted to do is to group the grains with similar orientations and link them to a particular cell on the sphere. Depending on the area of the cell, the number of grains grouped together will differ. So I am wondering how do I determine the range of angles that each area of the cell contains.

Comment: OK, it looks like we could draw lines of latitude on the sphere that would separate each ring of dots, and lines of longitude between each pair of dots in each ring, so that the entire surface is covered in little non-overlapping boxes of equal area. (The areas at the poles would necessarily not have four edges; you'd have either triangles with one corner at the pole or a single dot at the pole with a circle around it. I couldn't tell which one since the figure is a little obscure in that region.) If that helps, we could try to figure out a rule for the latitudes and longitudes.

Comment: Hi David, I added another image (in the post above) of the sphere from another angle so you can see the poles more clearly. Yes, that would be great - do you have an idea on how to proceed? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a set of "pixels" or points on the sphere arranged in rings,
that is, the pixels can be partitioned into subsets so that the pixels in each subset lie along one line of latitude at equal intervals.
I will call one such subset a ring of pixels.

I will suppose that the sphere is divided into zones between lines of latitude so that each zone contains one ring of pixels.
Each zone is then divided into bounding boxes by a set of lines of longitude so that each bounding box contains exactly one pixel.

We require that every bounding box in every zone have the same area.
We assume the pixels are placed in such a way that this is possible.
Within these constraints, we arrange the bounding boxes so that each pixel is as close to the center of its box as possible.

Let there be $n$ rings, with $p_k$ pixels in the $k$th ring, $1\leq k \leq n,$
numbered in sequence of latitude from one pole to the other.
The total number of pixels is
$$ P = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i = p_1 + p_2 + \cdots + p_n. $$

For simplicity, we suppose the radius of the sphere is $1.$
Then the area of the sphere is $4\pi$ and the area of the bounding box of each pixel is $4\pi/P.$

The combined area of all zones up to and including the one occupied by the $k$th ring is
$$ \frac{4\pi}{P} \sum_{i=1}^k p_i = \frac{4\pi}{P}(p_1 + p_2 + \cdots + p_k). $$
These zones occupy a spherical cap;
the area of a spherical cap is proportional to its height,
with the entire sphere considered as a cap of height equal to the sphere's diameter,
so the height of this spherical cap is
$$
\frac{\frac{4\pi}{P} \sum_{i=1}^k p_i}{4\pi} \cdot 2
= \frac 2P \sum_{i=1}^k p_i.
$$

This implies that the boundary of the cap (the line of latitude between ring number $k$ and ring number $k+1$) is at colatitude
$$ \arccos \left(1 - \frac 2P \sum_{i=1}^k p_i\right).$$

(Colatitude is like latitude, but measured starting from zero the pole instead of at the equator.)

The other boundary of the zone occupied by the $k$th ring is the boundary of the spherical cap occupied by the first $k-1$ rings, which is at colatitude
$$ \arccos \left(1 - \frac 2P \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} p_i\right).$$

So that is the range of colatitudes of the bounding box of a pixel in the $k$th ring; subtract from $\frac\pi2$ radians to get the range of latitudes.

Since there are $p_k$ equal-sized bounding boxes in a ring which is a total of $2\pi$ radians around, the angular "width" of each box (measured in radians) is $2\pi/p_k.$
If the longitude of the pixes is $\lambda$, then the range of longitudes of the bounding box is
$$\left[\lambda - \frac{2\pi}{p_k}, \lambda + \frac{2\pi}{p_k} \right]. $$

Comment: Hi David, thank you for the solutions and for the explanation. To follow up, using your equations, we can get the longitudes [a1,a2] and latitudes [b1,b2] of its bounding box. By doing a subtraction of A = (a1 - a2), and B = (b1 - b2) respectively, we get two angles A and B which represent the angular range of each bounding box. If, for example, the angles A and B are 10 and 5 degrees respectively, can I say that the grains are grouped together with a thresholding angle of 7.5 degrees (average of A and B)? Hope that is clear. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the correct way of combining the numbers into one number; I suppose it would depend on how that number was used. Maybe it should be measured corner-to-corner like a computer monitor. Maybe you should just take the solid angle of each box (which you can find just by dividing $4\pi$ by the number of pixels on a complete sphere) and compute the angle of a spherical cap with that area. Note that the exact dimensions of the boxes are the same in every ring but different between any two rings; the ring near the pole has $A=\pi/2$ (i.e. the boxes are $90$ degrees wide).

Comment: Okay, thank you for the suggestions and for the clarification!